# Other than the major histocompatibility complexes, what is the difference between professional and non-professional antigen presenting cells?

Tags: immunology, hematology, antigen

Can both professional and nonprofessional APCs activate helper T-cells? Or is that only macrophages and B-cells?

Do cytotoxic T-cells only make non-professional APCs go into apoptosis?